# AWS: How often Lambda face Cold Starts in production?

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, amazon-dynamodb, serverless

My company is developing a game using aws and I'm only backend developer.

Since I'm alone, I thought that going serverless would be easiest and safest solution for me.
I'm using .net core Lambdas with dynamodb as database as backend stack.

However, whenever cold start occurs response time of my login function takes around 16s 20s since dynamodb client initialization takes long. I load only 2mb data from db.

For development purposes, I have scheduled a lambda to avoid cold starts and I also know that I can provision some ready instances. But I think that scheduled calls will provision only one container and in production need will be a lot more. My company is also an advertising company so we expect a lot of users.

How much percentage of calls might face cold starts in production? Is is more then %20?

Also, I'm using terraform to manage infrastructure and I'm using route 53 + regional apigateways + custom domains setup to have multiple region latency based routing.

Would you recomment me to go beanstalk in stead of lambda? Its first time for me to create such environment that should be highly scalable.

Thank you
Kind regards

Comment: Your question is impossible to answer because it depends on how many requests your Lambda function is receiving, how many of those requests will be processed concurrently (which is a function of the request volume and the the time it takes for your function to handle a request), and if you have configured reserved concurrency or not. I will say that if it is taking more than 1 or 2 seconds to initialize your DynamoDB client then something is very wrong. 20 seconds for that is crazy high.

Comment: Especially with .net and Java lambdas it's important to make sure that there is sufficient memory as that also controls the CPU performance, I wouldn't go below 1024MB, aside from that I agree with @MarkB : impossible to answer.

Comment: dynamo db initialize takes 4 second and fetching 2-3 mb data from dynamo db takes 8 seconds... I dont get why it takes too long.. My functions and tables are in the same regions

Comment: It had 256 mb ram previously.. I tried with 512 mb ram now, cold start time decreased to 12s

Comment: Still wondering :(:(